# What If I compile the py manage.py collectstatics?

Tags: python, django

What If I compile the py manage.py collectstatics? I am on my localhost. I have configured all the s3 url accourding to given [url](https://stackabuse.com/serving-static-files-in-python-with-django-aws-s3-and-whitenoise/). We can see on last paragraph then it's telling run
`python manage.py collectstatic` .
My question is why we are doing this? Do we need to run this on every static or media changes? I tried to run this but it asking do you want to override this? Can I simply do yes? If I give yes then what will happen?

I am not much aware in this topic **collectstatics**

Comment: [collectstatic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic)

Comment: `collectstatic` only deals with *static* files. These are then collected in a special directory to make it easier for nginx/apache/... to serve static files. Typically that directory is not a (sub)directory of the code, to prevent people from obtaining the sourcecode.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Now I am very clear in this topic. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: thanks to both of you